# Built Scrapy spider, but it isn't following links

Tags: scrapy

I wrote a simple spider to get links of hikes. It seems like it isn't looking at the URLs at all to scrape the site:

```
[scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Here's my simple spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
 from scrapy.selector import Selector

 from oregon_hikes_scrapper.items import HikeLinkItem


 ENDPOINTS = [ 'from="%27%27Peter_Iredale%27%27&to=Bonney_Meadows-Hidden_Meadows_Trail_Junction', \
               'from=Bonney_Meadows-Hidden_Meadow_Trail_Junction&to=Clatsop_Loop_Hike',
             ]

 class OrHikeSpider(Spider):
     name ='or_hikes'
     allowed_domains = "oregonhikers.org"
     start_url = [
         "http://www.oregonhikers.org/field_guide/Special:AllPages&" + l for l in ENDPOINTS
     ]

     def parse(self, response):
         hikes = Selector.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a')

         for hike in hikes:
             item = HikeLinkItem()
             item['hike'] = hike.xpath('@title').extract()
             item['link'] = hike.xpath('@href').extract()
             yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error:

start_urls instead of start_url